# VUEJS Call a function in function (axios)

Tags: function, vue.js, axios

When I call this.func1() in func2, func1 return undefined.
Someone for help me please ?
I think the func return nothing because axios is not finished, how can I fix this ?

```
func1:function(val){
if(val.x == 0)
{
    axios.post('/...', {

    })
    .then((response) => {
        if(response.data == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return false;
    });
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}

//////
//////
//////


func2:function(variable){
    console.log(this.func1(variable)) // undefined..
    if(this.func1(variable) == true)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: function1 is async function.

Answer (score 0):

what about instead add `function 2` inside function 1 to call syncs.

```
func2:function(variable){
    console.log(this.func1(variable)) // undefined..


   func1:function(val){
if(val.x == 0)
{
    axios.post('/...', {

    })
    .then((response) => {
        if(response.data == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        return false;
    });
}
else
{
    return false;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Impossible in my case

Comment: func2 is called from DOM  on element with element.io (ui) "em-dropdown" with attribute "command="func2"

Comment: so what you exactly wan to check is `func1` from `func2` ?

Comment: func2(variable) contain "variable", but before doing the next of func2, func1 check if this "variable" can be modified

Comment: so you have to call `func1` inside  `func2` and any return for `func2` has to be inside `func1`